# My TableView is not populating with my custom cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to populate my `tableView` with a custom `cell` but whenever I run my app, the `tableView` always appears empty. Is there anything wrong with my code? I checked the identifiers and everything is correct. I also checked all the variables to see if they were `nil` but none of them were.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class StatisticsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var userArray : [UserString] = [UserString]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "DataCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "customMessageCell")
        configureTableView()
        loadInformation()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return userArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customMessageCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

        cell.heightLabel.text = "Height - " + userArray[indexPath.row].height
        cell.weightLabel.text = "Weight - " + userArray[indexPath.row].weight
        return cell
    }

    func loadInformation(){
        let messageDB = Database.database().reference().child("Users")
    messageDB.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
            let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String,String>
            let email = snapshotValue["UserEmail"]!
            if (email == Auth.auth().currentUser?.email as String?){
                let user : UserString = UserString()
                user.name = snapshotValue["UserName"]!
                user.height = snapshotValue["UserHeight"]! + " cm"
                user.weight = snapshotValue["UserWeight"]! + " kg"
                user.date = snapshotValue["EntryDate"]!
                self.userArray.append(user)                
                self.configureTableView()
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

        }
    }

    func configureTableView(){
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 120.0
    }
}
```

Comment: this condition if (email == Auth.auth().currentUser?.email as String?) is true?

Comment: Maybe the problem is in background thread, try dispatching observe block on the main thread

Comment: `self.tableView.reloadData()` this in main queue. Why are you calling `self.configureTableView()` method multiple times, calling it in `viewDidLoad` method is enough. As you're using `automaticDimension` height you really need to check the content you're passing for cell is not empty otherwise cell height will be 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with static height I think there is constraints related problem in your cell that's why `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` not Working Try This with static height if it works then look over cell constraints.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

     return 100.0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by changing hierarchy of statements first register nib and then call `delegate` and `dataSource` Also check data is not empty.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "DataCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "customMessageCell")  
   tableView.delegate = self
   tableView.dataSource = self
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
   configureTableView()
   loadInformation()
}
```